# Proving S (n + m) = n + (S m), how to rewrite n+1 = S(n)?

Tags: coq, gallina

```
Theorem add_0_r : forall n:nat, n + 0 = n.
Proof.
  intros n. induction n as [| n' IHn'].
  - (* n = 0 *) reflexivity.
  - (* n = S n' *) simpl. rewrite -> IHn'. reflexivity. Qed.

Theorem plus_n_Sm : forall n m : nat,
  S (n + m) = n + (S m).
Proof.
  intros n m. induction m as [| m' IHn']. rewrite -> add_0_r. rewrite <- sum.
```

The last tactic `rewirte <- sum` does not work. This is the goal:

```
n: ℕ
-------------
S(n) = n + 1
```

I don't know how to rewrite `n+1` as `S(n)`. I think that `n+1` is just a notation for `S(n)`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `+` as follows, you can see that it is defined by induction on its first argument:

```
Locate "+". (* to obtain the name Nat.add *)
Print Nat.add.
(*
Nat.add =
fix add (n m : nat) {struct n} : nat :=
  match n with
  | 0 => m
  | S p => S (add p m)
  end
     : nat -> nat -> nat
*)
```

As a result `1 + n` is indeed convertible to `S n` (you can see that using `Eval cbn in 1 + ?[n].`) but not `n + 1` (if you `unfold Nat.add.` you will obtain a pattern match stuck on the variable `n`).

For your proof, that specific definition of `+` means that you might reconsider your approach and try to do your proof by induction on `n` rather than `m` (paying attention to have the right induction hypothesis).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `nat` type from the standard library, then `n+1` is not a notation for `S n`, but a notation for the function `Nat.add`. In that case `n+1` is not apparently equal to `S n`. You need to prove it by an induction on `n`.

By the way, if you are using `Nat.nat`, you need to use induction on `n` rather than `m`. Because `Nat.add` is defined by a `match` on the first argument. In this case, your first subgoal of the induction can be proved simply by `reflexivity.` (Coq is able to simplify `S (0 + m)` and `0 + S m`, but not `S (n + 0)` and `n + 1`).

Comment: how can Coq simplify `S(0+m)` as `S(m) + 0`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70491391/13684332 how did the last `simpl. ` work? How did Coq now?

Comment: When comparing objects for equality, Coq uses the definitions of functions and performs computations.  There are many ways in which definitions can be used, and `simpl` just tries to follow heuristically the way one would think about a recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to prove with the following:

```
Theorem plus_n_Sm : forall n m : nat,
  S (n + m) = n + (S m).
Proof.
  intros n m. induction n as [| n' IHn']. 
  - simpl. reflexivity.
  - simpl. rewrite -> IHn'. reflexivity.
Qed.
```